# Output not right on Descending Selection Sort

Tags: python

I am working on an assignment and I am really struggling to figure out what I am doing wrong. I am new to Python, and honestly, I barely understand the code I have cobbled together so far.

What I have currently is:

```
array=[int(n) for n in input().split()]

for i in range(len(array)):
    max_index = i
    for j in range(i+1, len(array)):
        if int(array[j]) > int(array[max_index]):
            max_index = j
    array[i],array[max_index] = array[max_index],array[i]

    print(array)
```

With the input of

```
50 40 20 10 30
```

I get:

```
[50, 40, 20, 10, 30]
[50, 40, 20, 10, 30]
[50, 40, 30, 10, 20]
[50, 40, 30, 20, 10]
[50, 40, 30, 20, 10]
```

What I need is:

```
[50, 40, 20, 10, 30]
[50, 40, 20, 10, 30]
[50, 40, 30, 10, 20]
[50, 40, 30, 20, 10]
```

Comment: Your outer loop executes once for each item in the array (i=0,1,2,3,4). So it will execute 5 times. Did you maybe want to run it for n-1 times? Checking the last item is pointless in this algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the below code, here checking that array is sorted using a flag and stop processing for loop after sorted, it will improve time complexity of algorithm.

```
array=[int(n) for n in input().split()]

for i in range(len(array)):
    max_index = i
    is_sorted = True
    for j in range(i + 1, len(array)):
        if int(array[j]) > int(array[max_index]):
            max_index = j
            is_sorted = False

    if (is_sorted == True):
        break
    array[i],array[max_index] = array[max_index],array[i]
    print(array)
```

Input: 50 40 30 20 10   (i.e. sorted array and it prints None as its sorted)

Output:

Input: 10 20 30 40 50    (i.e. unsorted array and it prints till it sorted & break)

Output:
[50, 20, 30, 40, 10]

[50, 40, 30, 20, 10]

Comment: This appears to work, except in one really weird instance.

With input of

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

I get output of


[9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1]
[9, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 1]
[9, 8, 7, 4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

And it expects

[9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1]
[9, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 1]
[9, 8, 7, 4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

The output by your code makes far more sense. Why would the system expect all those additional rows?

Comment: My python version: 3.8.2 (default, Mar 13 2020, 10:14:16). I am not getting any expected row from system. Please try in another version Or machine

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between the actual and expected output is that it outputs the sorted array an additional time. If you're looking to stop sorting whenever the array is sorted, you can add a `break` statement to terminate the loop early:

```py
def is_sorted_descending(array):
    for i in range(len(array) - 1):
        if array[i] < array[i + 1]:
            return False
    return True

for i in range(len(array)):
    max_index = i
    for j in range(i+1, len(array)):
        if int(array[j]) > int(array[max_index]):
            max_index = j
    array[i],array[max_index] = array[max_index],array[i]

    print(array)
    
    if is_sorted_descending(array):
        break
```

Comment: Iterating through an array to check if it is sorted might make sense in some situations, but doing it in **every step of a sorting algorithm** is not a great idea. Even though it technically doesn't affect the time complexity of this code.

Comment: I agree, but OP's expected output demands that the algorithm terminate once the input is sorted. **Whether this is a good idea in practice is a separate question entirely and isn't relevant to what OP was asking for.** (OP indicated that this was an assignment, and in practice you would use a different sorting algorithm with a better time complexity.)

Comment: I'm not sure why you think the requirement is that the algorithm terminates early once the array sorted. The output has 4 prints because the [correct algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort#Implementations) terminates in n-1 iterations. If OP can confirm that a sorted input should lead to only 1 print, then yes you would be correct.

Comment: There are multiple implementations of selection sort that can produce a correct output, so I'd hesitate to say that anything that doesn't terminate in n - 1 iterations is incorrect. But fair enough.